# How to make particular rows in Excel spreadsheet read-only via VBA Macro?

Tags: excel, vba

This is my problem. I need my VBA macro to make a particular number of top rows (let say, N) in an Excel spreadsheet read-only, so a user would not be able to change them by mistake. Still, I need a user to be able to edit and change other rows in the same spreadsheet. If I do something like

```
   Range("A1:J10").Select
   Selection.Locked  = True
   ActiveSheet.Protect Contents:=True
```

then the whole spreadsheet is getting locked. If, on the other hand, I omit `ActiveSheet.Protect Contents:=True` line (do not protect the sheet), nothing is getting locked at all.

So, the question is: is it possible to block only the specified rows, while allowing user to edit the rest of them? I would appreciate the VBA code doing that.

Answer (score 2):

By default all cells on a sheet are Locked=True, but this has no effect until the sheet is protected.

You will need to *unlock* the cells you want to stay editable before the sheet is protected.